# Write-EventLog within Function over Remote PowerShell

Tags: events, powershell, logging, event-log

The environment:
Server: Windows Server 2012 R2 with Remote PowerShell enabled.
Workstation: Windows 8.1

So I've created a PowerShell Module called MyModule.psm1 with the following function:

```
Function CreateEvent() {

Write-EventLog –LogName ToolLog –Source “Schedule” –EntryType Information –EventID 13 –Message “There were users written to the database.”

}
```

I created a PSSessionConfigurationFile and then registered it with a configuration name of EventLogging, so that I can remote powershell via the following:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
$SessionOpts = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server.Domain.Com -ConfigurationName EventLogging -Credential $Creds -UseSSL -SessionOption $SessionOpts
Import-PSSession $Session
```

Now, when I enter a Local Administrators credentials into the Get-Credential, I can run the function CreateEvent and everything works just fine.  However, if I enter a Standard Local Users credentials, I get an error of: The registry key for the log "ToolLog" for source "Schedule" could not be opened.

I replaced the Write-EventLog in the Function with:

```
$EventLog = new-object System.Diagnostics.EventLog("ToolLog");
$EventLog.MachineName = ".";
$EventLog.Source = "Schedule";
$EventLog.WriteEntry("There were users written to the database.", "Information", 15);
```

And I receive an error of: Exception calling "WriteEntry" with "3" argument(s): "Cannot open log for source 'Schedule'. You may not have write access."

If I log on to the server locally and Import the Module and try to run the function I get the same exact errors.  I also cannot run the cmdlet of Write-EventLog by itself.

From all of the information I found on the internet, I've give my local non-admin user write permissions to the event log.  Both through RegEdit and through NTFS on the actual Event Log file.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Hi Brian, Did you get any where with this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that only Administrators can create new event logs. I'm not sure if there is a way around this or not. I suggest adding the new event log on your server as an administrator ahead of time so that the event log is there before non-administrators try to write to it.

Comment: Hey Aaron, So I've already got the event log created from an administrator account.  It's when I'm trying to write an event to that event log that I receive the errors.